# My PC seems to be slow although I'm using an SSD

Tags: filesystem, performance

I have an SSD with NTFS format.

My question is, does the NTFS format affect the performance of a Linux system, or is it unrelated?

Comment: No, it won't impact the performance

Answer (score 1):

The results of this Phoronix benchmarking test show that performance on NTFS filesystem is slower than on ext4,

| File system type | Copy 655MB (1) | Copy 655MB (2) | tar gzip 655MB | unzip untar 655MB | Del 2.5GB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REISER4 gzip | 213 | 148 | 68 | 83 | 48 |
| REISER4 lzo | 278 | 138 | 56 | 80 | 34 |
| REISER4 tails | 673 | 148 | 63 | 78 | 33 |
| REISER4 | 692 | 148 | 55 | 67 | 25 |
| NTFS3g | 772 | 1333 | 1426 | 585 | 767 |
| NTFS | 779 | 781 | 173 | X | X |
| REISER3 | 793 | 184 | 98 | 85 | 63 |
| XFS | 799 | 220 | 173 | 119 | 90 |
| JFS | 806 | 228 | 202 | 95 | 97 |
| EXT4 extents | 806 | 162 | 55 | 69 | 36 |
| EXT4 default | 816 | 174 | 70 | 74 | 42 |
| EXT3 | 816 | 182 | 74 | 73 | 43 |
| EXT2 | 816 | 201 | 82 | 73 | 39 |
| FAT32 | 988 | 253 | 158 | 118 | 81 |

The raw data (without filesystem meta-data, block alignment wastage, etc.) was 655MB.
It comprised 3 different copies of the Linux kernel sources.

Disk Usage: the amount of disk used to store the data
Copy 655MB (1): time taken to copy the data over a partition boundary
Copy 655MB (2): time taken to copy the data within a partition
tar gzip 655MB: time taken to tar and gzip the data
unzip untar 655MB: time taken to ungzip and untar the data
Del 2.5 Gig: time taken to delete everything just written (about 2.5 Gig)

Each test was preformed 5 times and the average value recorded. <sup>[source](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/general-linux-open-source/1468-performance-of-filesystems-compared-includes-reiser4-and-ext4?t=1765)</sup>

---

The main advantage of the NTFS filesystem over ext4 is that it is recognized natively by Windows. NTFS suffers from file fragmentation. This adds wear and tear to your hardware as well as slowing the system down. ext4 is immune to this as long as you are not running really low on disk space.